# How does one get "Reputation" points

Tags: discussion, questions

Just as a notice, I'm new to this site, and I found a question that I was willing to answer to a certain person, but the system asks me for 50 reputation points. How is this earned? I'm not sure if I am missing anything.

Comment: You don't need 50 points to answer a question, only to comment. This is a comment; down below this is an actual answer (by Mick). One of the quickest ways to earn reputation is to write good answers, which get upvoted (notice the big up and down buttons next to both your question and Mick's answer). So if you have a good answer to someone's question, go ahead and scroll down to the bottom of the page where you'll see the heading "Your answer" followed by a large text box. Find info on [writing good answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center. Good luck!

Comment: Guys, you don’t need to downvote a newcomer who’s actively looking into how to participate, and is clearly keen to *earn* rep. Geez.

Answer (score 1):

See the relevant help page:

[What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)